# Responsive logo and navigation menu Divi Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a site with the Divi theme for Wordpress. I have a different logo for the menu when you are scrolling down the page, a smaller version. 
However, in smartphones and small screens the hamburger menu gets bellow the logo, while it should be on the right side of it. I am putting a photo so you can see what I am talking about.

[I am marking with a line where the hamburguer menu should go.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EevYD.png)

Here I put also the code I used to edit the logo.

> **#logo2 {display: none;}**
>
> **.et-fixed-header #logo {display:none;}**
>
> **.et-fixed-header #logo2 {display:inline;}**
>
> **#logo { padding-top: 10px !important; }**
>
> **#logo2 { max-height: 60px !important; padding-top: 15px !important; }**

The Website in case you want to take a look to see how the menu is working is www.masqueglobos.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just Add this to the end of your CSS ...

```
.et_header_style_left #et-top-navigation {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 30px !important;
}
```

the problem is there is padding that push the btn down .

Comment: Thank you very much. That was perfet.